# How to write items from array randomly?

Tags: c#

I have an array. I would like to write its items in a random order every time I call. My array is this.

```
string[] a= {"A","B","C","D","F"};
string[] a= new string[5];
```

For example the order should be like this

C
D
F
A
B

But it should change the order.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864921/how-can-i-randomize-numbers-in-an-array

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this:

```
string[] a = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "F" };
Random rand = new Random();
string[] RandArray = a.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
string[] RandArray = a.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToArray();
//any of these works.
```