# BlackJack Game Deck Class Trouble

Tags: c#

I am creating a blackjack game and so far I have made a card class, I started to make a deck class but I am not sure on how to set up the cards with values taken from the arrays. Also I have to use the arrays in my deck class to do this.

Any help would be appreciated

Here is what I have so far for my deck class

```
class Deck
{
    private const Int32 MAXCARDS = 52;
    private Card[] _cards = new Card[MAXCARDS];
    Card.SUIT[] suits = { Card.SUIT.SPADES, Card.SUIT.HEARTS, Card.SUIT.DIAMONDS, Card.SUIT.CLUBS };
    String[] values = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };

    public Card()
    {

    }
    public Card GetCard(Int32 index)
    {

    }

    public Card SetCard(Int32 index, Card Card)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532939/1070452) has the framework for a Card and Deck classes including how to shuffle.

Comment: Looks like some homework? I can offer a hint based on where I think you might be stuck. While there are indeed 52 cards, each card has to be represented by both a value and a suit at the same time. I would assume such a relationship to reside within the Card class. Why would the deck class care what the suit and/or value of a card is? It just knows there are N number of cards in the deck and doesn't have to know what the cards are. My hint here is that suits and values might not being to the Deck class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to spoil the whole action, concentrate on the points where you struggle and try to code further without help :)

```
 class Card
 {
     public enum SUIT { SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS };

     public string Value {get; set;}
     public SUIT Suit { get; set; }

     public Card(SUIT suit, string value)
     {
         this.Suit = suit;
         this.Value = value;
     }
 }
 class Deck
 {
     private const Int32 MAXCARDS = 52;
     private Card[] _cards = new Card[MAXCARDS];

     public Deck()
     {
         Card.SUIT[] suits = { Card.SUIT.SPADES, Card.SUIT.HEARTS, Card.SUIT.DIAMONDS, Card.SUIT.CLUBS };
         String[] values = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };
         Random rnd = new Random();
         Card[] orderedCards = new Card[suits.Length * values.Length];
         int newIndex = 0;

         // Generate an array with all possible combinations of suits and values
         for (int suitsIndex = 0; suitsIndex < suits.Length; suitsIndex++)
         {
             for (int valuesIndex = 0; valuesIndex < values.Length; valuesIndex++)
             {
                 newIndex = values.Length * suitsIndex + valuesIndex; // Think about it :)
                 orderedCards[newIndex] = new Card(suits[suitsIndex], values[valuesIndex]);
             }
         }

         // Generate an array with random numbers from 0 51 (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864921/how-can-i-randomize-numbers-in-an-array)
         int[] randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, this._cards.Length).OrderBy(r => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

         // Now go from 0 to 51 and set a card to a random element of the orderedCards array
         for (int i = 0; i < _cards.Length; i++)
         {
             this._cards[i] = orderedCards[randomNumbers[i]];
             Console.WriteLine("Card " + i + " = " + _cards[i].Suit.ToString() + " - " + _cards[i].Value.ToString());
         }
     }
 }
```